# Get selected option in php without pressing submit

Tags: php, html

How to get the value of the selected option in php

```
    <select id="select" name="select">
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
      <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: can't. Need to use jquery/javascript

Comment: PHP is a server side language. It only sees changes you've made to the form after you've clicked submit (i.e. submitted the form *to the server*).

Comment: @symlink  also ajax data processed by PHP too

Comment: @AlivetoDie true, but same concept, data needs to be sent to the server for PHP to process it, and it would be overkill to ping the server for something like this, JavaScript can easily handle it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side language. So without submitting anything to the server, you can't find what option has been selected. However, if you want to find it with JavaScript or the jQuery library, you could do something like this:

Using vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("select").onchange = function() {
    // find what option the user changed to!    
    var option = document.getElementById("select").value;
    // alert with the option
    alert("Select changed to: " + option);
};
```

Using jQuery library:

```
// uses jQuery's .change() for a <select> element
$("#select").change(function() {
    // find what option the user changed to!
    var option = $("#select option:selected").text();
    // alert with the option
    alert("Select changed to: " + option);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a php file which creates a database table( mysql or mariadb can be used) then in that table you have to redirect the value of form by assigning the php file to the action button and then the value of that option will get restored in that database.
I will prefer to use phpmyadmin, you can create database in it without code and can link it to your file. But if you want to really learn this then i will suggest that first learn php and mysql from a decent website like w3schools because if you simply copy the code than you will not understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is serverside programming language and it can get values from post , get and cookies and ... . you have to submit form to send values through GET or ... . Best way to do this is using ajax .

```
`$('#select').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax(
    /* your code here */
    );
 }).
```